# Unable to set-up MariaDB on Arch Linux / Permission Denied on mysql_install_db

Tags: mariadb

Having trouble setting-up MariaDB. I'm following [Arch Linux | MariaDB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MySQL)

I installed MariaDB on Arch Linux `sudo pacman -S mariadb`

I've created a new folder `/mnt/local/int001/MEDIA/Personal/DB` with permissions:

```
drwxrwsr-x+ 1 mysql mysql                232 Jul 13 14:34  DB
```

I add `datadir = /mnt/local/int001/MEDIA/Personal/DB` to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

I added my user to the `mysql` user group `sudo usermod -a -G mysql myuser`

I then try to run `sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/mnt/local/int001/MEDIA/Personal/DB` as recommended, but get the following errors. Any ideas why I'm getting this even though `mysql` has ownership.

EDIT: I've since changed permissions to 777, makes no difference.

EDIT: There is no trace of SELinux on my system.

EDIT: There was ACLs, but I've removed them from the parent (and recursively).

EDIT: I've changed to `SU mysql` and can edit files at this path.

```
Installing MariaDB/MySQL system tables in '/mnt/local/int001/MEDIA/Personal/DB' ...

2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] /usr/bin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.34-MariaDB) starting as process 12074 ...
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/mnt/local/int001/MEDIA/Personal/DB/aria_log_control' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't create file' when trying to use aria control file '/mnt/local/int001/MEDIA/Personal/DB/aria_log_control'
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-07-13 14:52:02 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-07-13 14:52:03 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-07-13 14:52:03 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-07-13 14:52:03 140714278559680 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.39-83.1 started; log sequence number 1600627
2018-07-13 14:52:03 140713784243968 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2018-07-13 14:52:03 140714278476544 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't existERROR: 1  Can't create/write to file '/mnt/local/int001/MEDIA/Personal/DB/mysql/db.MYI' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2018-07-13 14:52:03 140714278559680 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but try to relax permissions on parent directory, I have seen such behavior some time ago. If I remember correctly it was caused by "too strict" permissions.
Second guess, have you tried to add 'trailing slash' to the path ?

Comment: I've given the parent 777, but no difference and always tried with a trailing slash, also no change.

Comment: Ok, and if you do su mysql. Then try to create that file, write something to it?  Oh, and selinux. Is it enabled?

Comment: I've SUd to mysql and can edit files at /mnt/local/int001/MEDIA/Personal/DB fine.  SELinux doesn't appear to be activated in Arch unless it's a hardened distro and I can't find any mention of 'selinux' on my install.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add recursive permissions on that path so mysqld can access it.

`chmod -R <permissions> <path>`

The same can apply with `chown -R`

Also, adding your filesystem info can help.

Comment: Some files weren't 777, so I've ensured everything from DB down is mysql:mysql and 777.  Still same issue.  I created the aria_log_control file that it complains about fine, ran the install again, still complains about it as though it's not being run under mysql